# Want to read user credentials from excel using selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to retrive user credentials from .xlsx excel version. I have written the code for retrieving data from excel but am unable to insert the date into appication. Please help me out.

```
FileInputStream stream=new FileInputStream("D:/Ravi-Training/ExcelRead.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook wb=new XSSFWorkbook(stream);
    XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
    /*Iterator<Row> rt=sheet.iterator();
    while(rt.hasNext())
    {
        Row row=rt.next();
        Iterator<Cell> ct=row.cellIterator();
        while(ct.hasNext())
        {
            Cell cell=ct.next();
        }*/
    System.out.println(sheet.getSheetName());
    System.out.println(sheet.getLastRowNum());
    XSSFRow row=sheet.getRow(1);
    XSSFCell cell1=row.getCell(0);
    XSSFCell cell2=row.getCell(1);
    XSSFCell cell3=row.getCell(2);
    System.out.println(cell1);
    System.out.println(cell2);
    System.out.println(cell3);
```

Comment: what you mean unable to insert.. do you mean that you will unable to get data from excel.

Comment: You need to provide WAY more details on what you have tried and what the results were. It's unclear what you are asking. Have you verified that you are able to read the data from Excel? Have you tried inserting a hard coded string into the application? Be thorough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    FileInputStream fs=new FileInputStream("Path of excel sheet");
    Workbook wb1=WorkbookFactory.create(fs);
    Sheet sh=wb1.getSheetAt(0);
    Row row=sh.createRow(8);
    //Write data
    Cell cell=row.createCell(8);
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
    cell.setCellValue("ravi");
    FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream("Path of excel sheet");
    wb1.write(fos);
    fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath));
        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        XSSFSheet sheet = null;

        if (sheetobj instanceof Integer) {
            sheet = wb.getSheetAt((int) sheetobj);
        }
        if (sheetobj instanceof String) {
            sheet = wb.getSheet((String) sheetobj);
        }

        Iterator<Row> rowIt = sheet.rowIterator();

        Row row = rowIt.next();

        int noOfrow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
        int noOfcolumn = row.getLastCellNum();

        excelValue = new String[noOfrow][noOfcolumn];

        System.out.println("No: of column " + noOfcolumn + " no: of row " + noOfrow);

        wb.close();
```

hope this helps.